# Unicode Characters to recreate the C64 random maze program

Tags: windows, unicode, console-application, windows-console, c64

I want to recreate a simple C64 Random Maze using Unicode characters.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m9joBLOZVEo

I can't find good line characters that always produce a consistent, skewed line. / and \ don't work for me, neither do "\u2571" and "\u2572".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try different fonts.  On Windows, MS Gothic worked best (Python code):

[image: Python code to simulate C64 maze]